# How can I get lock screen controls to show up on iPhone when using multiple HTML audio elements?

Tags: html, ios, reactjs, audio, mediasession

I'm using four HTML audio elements in a page in a React application and would like to get the lock screen media controls (play, pause, next, previous etc.) to show up on iPhone, which I'd like to customise with [Media Session API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Session_API). It does show up sometimes but for some reason it's intermittent, maybe coming up one in four times. When I only use one audio element it always comes up.

And for some reason it will always come up when I click play, pause and then play again before locking the screen.

This is the code (I've removed the URLs for the audio sources but they're correct on my side)

```
class App extends Component<IAppProps, IAppState> {
    private vocals: HTMLAudioElement;
    private other: HTMLAudioElement;
    private bass: HTMLAudioElement;
    private drums: HTMLAudioElement;

    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);

        this.vocals = new Audio();
        this.other = new Audio();
        this.bass = new Audio();
        this.drums = new Audio();

        this.vocals.src = '';
        this.other.src = '';
        this.bass.src = '';
        this.drums.src = '';

        this.vocals.load();
        this.other.load();
        this.bass.load();
        this.drums.load();

        if ('mediaSession' in navigator) {
            navigator.mediaSession.metadata = new MediaMetadata({
              title: 'Unforgettable',
              artist: 'Nat King Cole',
              album: 'The Ultimate Collection (Remastered)',
              artwork: [
                { src: 'https://dummyimage.com/96x96',   sizes: '96x96',   type: 'image/png' },
                { src: 'https://dummyimage.com/128x128', sizes: '128x128', type: 'image/png' },
                { src: 'https://dummyimage.com/192x192', sizes: '192x192', type: 'image/png' },
                { src: 'https://dummyimage.com/256x256', sizes: '256x256', type: 'image/png' },
                { src: 'https://dummyimage.com/384x384', sizes: '384x384', type: 'image/png' },
                { src: 'https://dummyimage.com/512x512', sizes: '512x512', type: 'image/png' },
              ]
            });
        }

        this.state = {
            playbackState: 'paused',
        }
    }

    handlePlayClick = () => {
        const { playbackState } = this.state;

        if (playbackState === 'paused') {
            this.setState({ playbackState: 'playing'});
            navigator.mediaSession.playbackState = 'playing';
            this.vocals.play();
            this.other.play();
            this.bass.play();
            this.drums.play();
        } else {
            this.setState({ playbackState: 'paused'});
            navigator.mediaSession.playbackState = 'paused';
            this.vocals.pause();
            this.other.pause();
            this.bass.pause();
            this.drums.pause();
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <button onClick={this.handlePlayClick}>{this.state.playbackState === 'paused' ? 'PLAY' : 'PAUSE'}</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```